# How to export Parties and Agreements from BizTalk Server 2013 R2?

Tags: upgrade, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

We are going with Standalone parallel installation of BizTalk server 2020 instead inplace upgrade.
I am looking for an option to copy Trading Partner party's and Agreements from old server to new server. All up to date party's and agreements only present on one server which were added manually. The out of the box option to export and import only available from 2016 or later.
Any suggestions or ideas to handle it automatically would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I couldn't find an workable automated solution yet. I had tried vai database scripts but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Export bindings and check Export Global Party information.  This is available in BizTalk 2013 R2.

[image: Export Bindings]

Comment: Thanks for your response. It worked to export all the parties. I couldn't directly import on 2020 server, getting a SQL exception. Looks like something on new server to be reviewed. Thanks!